# How to reset repository to initial state on git

Tags: git, github

I have a repository in github and i want reset this repo to initial state
The initial state is the state without any commits and not connected to any projects
Please help me how to do this

i try to git log and git reset but it only change to first commit

Comment: delete and recreate?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/drop the commits you don't want to.

If you made any commits using GitHub, commits will tagged as `Verified`. You can't remove `Verified` commits.

But you can remove the commits that are created using git itself.

- First, `git rebase -i HEAD~X` change the X with how many commits you want to edit (etc: `HEAD~2` for the last 2 commits).
- Then in the opened editor, change `pick` to `drop`. Save and exit.

> **WARNING**: This will delete the commits and changes.

- Afterward, force push to the repository using `git push origin master --force` (It can be `main` if you didn't change the main branch name)